# index was outside the bounds of the array double C# (double)

Tags: c#

I've been trying to implement Bresenham's line algorithm from the [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) and I've encountered a strange issue that leads to an exception.

```
public static int[,] Line(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
    {
        int arraySizeX = x1 - x0;
        int arraySizeY = y1 - y0;
        int [,] outputArray = new int[arraySizeX, arraySizeY];
        //Bresenham's line algorithm from Wikipedia
        double deltax = x1 - x0;
        double deltay = y1 - y0;

        double deltaerr = Math.Abs(deltay / deltax); // Assume deltax != 0 (line is not vertical),
        double error;
        error = 0.0;//no error at start
        int y = 0;

        for( int x = x0; x1 >= x; x++)
        {
            outputArray[x, y] = 1;
            error += deltaerr;
            while(error >= 0.5)
            {
                y = y + Math.Sign(deltay) * 1;
                error = error - 1.0;
            }
        }

        return outputArray;
    }
```

And when I test it with:

```
Line(2, 1, 5, 3);
```

it return the exception:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

At this line:

```
                error += deltaerr;
```

This happens on the second iteration of the for loop.
At that point the two values are:

> ```
>   error   -0.33333333333333337    double
> ```

and

> ```
>   deltaerr    0.66666666666666663 double
> ```

In my mind error should be assigned something like 0.3333.
Any pointers as to what may have gone wrong?

This is my first question, so please tell me how I could improve in future. Thanks.

> Solution: Pay close attention to all arrays in the code.

**The error was actually on the line above** where the code tried to reference an array position that didn't exist.

Comment: Given input:

   `Line(2, 1, 5, 3);`

the multidimensional array is essentially defined as

    `int [,] outputArray = new int[3, 2];`

you can think of this as a table of 3 rows and 2 columns. however, the issue is that the for loop iteration variable `x` goes beyond the number of rows available. you can easily sort this out by using a debugger and making sure your algorithm is correct.

Comment: The error `IndexOutOfRangeException` cannot happen at this line `error += deltaerr;`, because this line does not involve any indexing. It must this one `outputArray[x, y] = 1;`, where the array is indexed with`[x, y]`. I explain it in detail in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The exception occurs on the line above, when you try to access the array.

```
outputArray[x, y] = 1;
```

---

When you call your method `Line(2, 1, 5, 3);` you will create an array of the size `new int[3,2]`

```
int arraySizeX = x1 - x0;  //  5 - 2 = 3
int arraySizeY = y1 - y0;  //  3 - 1 = 2
int [,] outputArray = new int[arraySizeX, arraySizeY]; // new int[3,2]
```

So now your `for` loop will run from `x0 = 2` to `x1=5` so you are running out of the array range. This is what your exception is about.

---

To fix this you should start your `for` loop by `x = 0` and end by `x <= x1-x0-1` or start by `x = 0` and end by `x < x1-x0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an array with

```
new int[arraySizeX, arraySizeY]
```

then the index ranges are

```
[0 .. arraySizeX - 1, 0 .. arraySizeY - 1]
```

You must never exceed these limits. Subtract `x0` or `y0` from the coordinates to get indexes that are within these limits

```
for (int x = x0; x1 >= x; x++)
{
    outputArray[x - x0, y - y0] = 1;
    ...
}
```

Another problem is that you are looping until `x == x1`. Therefore the array size should be `int arraySizeX = x1 - x0 + 1`. Same for `arraySizeY` (because if `y0 == y1`, i.e. the line is horizontal, the array size must be 1, not 0).

(Also assuming that `x1 > x0` and `y1 >= y0`, otherwise you might get negative array sizes)

---

But a more realistic approach would "draw" the pixels into an array that reflects the image size instead of just the line size and the end-points of the line would have to be within the image. An extra logic would clip lines crossing the image boundaries. See: [Cohen–Sutherland algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm) for [Line clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping).

```
int[,] image = new int[imageWidth, imageHeight];
```

With `x0` and `x1` in the range `[0 .. imageWidth-1]` and `y0` and `y1` in the range `[0 .. imageHeight-1]`.